On the scope of a mutable variable with respect to a loop block
While learning Rust, I don't quite understand how a mutable variable is treated in a loop block. In particular, an immutable variable become mutable by adding a mut before its name. Then, one can change its value as many as they want.
So, my initial try in the small code below was like:
use rand::Rng;
use std::io;
use std::cmp::Ordering;

fn main() 
{
    let secret_number = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1..=100);
    
    let mut guess = String::new();

    loop {
        println!("Guess the number!");
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut guess).expect("Failed to readline");
        let guess: u32 = match guess.trim().parse() {
            Ok(num) => num,
            Err(_) => continue,
        };
        match guess.cmp(&secret_number) {
            Ordering::Less => println!("Too small!"),
            Ordering::Greater => println!("Too large"),
            Ordering::Equal => {
                println!("You win!");
                break;
            }    
        }
    }
}

My expectation was that mut guess can be defined outside of the loop because its value can be later changed in the loop. However, if one runs the code, the comparing block in the loop executes only for the first guess.
I figured out that mut guess declaration must be in the loop, as well, just like the code below. However, I don't understand why the code above does not work. In other words, why does one have to constantly redefine mut guess in the loop instead of defining it only once outside of the loop?
use rand::Rng;
use std::io;
use std::cmp::Ordering;

fn main() 
{
    let secret_number = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1..=100);
    
    loop {
        let mut guess = String::new();
        println!("Guess the number!");
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut guess).expect("Failed to readline");
        let guess: u32 = match guess.trim().parse() {
            Ok(num) => num,
            Err(_) => continue,
        };
        match guess.cmp(&secret_number) {
            Ordering::Less => println!("Too small!"),
            Ordering::Greater => println!("Too large"),
            Ordering::Equal => {
                println!("You win!");
                break;
            }    
        }
    }
}

which yields to a compiler error.
